# R dplyr How to perform left_join with different keys when one key is not available

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, key, left-join

How can I perform a left_join using `dplyr` with two different keys and then, when the second key is not available, join the tables by using only the first key.

Thanks you

**EDIT**

Here is the logic:

If the two keys are found in the dataset, use both keys. If the second key is not found (`NA` or no matching) in the dataset, use only the first one as merging key.

Comment: Hi John, it will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your two data.frames with `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)`, the code you've tried so far, and importantly your expected output. You can [edit] your question and paste the output. Please surround the output with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something along these lines:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  key1 = c("A", "B"),
  key2 = c(1, 2),
  value_df1 = runif(2)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  key1 = c("A", "B"),
  key2 = c(1, NA),
  value_df2 = runif(2)
)

df_merged <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("key1", "key2")) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% select(-key2), by = "key1") %>%
  mutate(value2 = coalesce(value_df2.x, value_df2.y)) %>%
  select(key1, key2, value_df1, value_df2)
```

Comment: Not exactly. If the two keys are inside the dataset, use both keys. If the second key is not in the dataset, use only the first one as merging key. I am not sure if your solution works